How to refer to a different sheet based on the value of a cell?
I have an excel file with multiple sheets (Day1, Day2, Day3, etc. with no spaces).

On the master sheet I need to be able to pull certain data from each sheet when I select a value from a drop down menu. I already have the drop down menu setup for Day1, Day2, Day3, etc. and I need the formula to retrieve certain data from respective sheet when that sheet name is selected from the drop down menu.
The formula I use is:
=(COUNTIF('Day2'!$P$6:$U$46,$B42)/6)/24
Basically it counts how many times the value from cell B42 on master sheet is appearing in the P6-U46 range from Day2 tab. What I need is basically when I change the drop down menu value from Day2 to Day3, then all formula references to Day2 to automatically change to Day3. I know I can use the CTRL H but I am looking for a more elegant solution.
I tried INDIRECT() a bit but cannot seem to find a formula to include INDIRECT() and COUNTIF() to do what I need. I tried the INDIRECT() formulas as well as some INDEX() variations but could not find a working formula.

This question is similar to: How to dynamically link sheet name to count data from that sheet. If you believe it’s different, please edit the question, make it clear how it’s different and/or how the answers on that question are not helpful for your problem.

how a bout something along the lines: =LET(d,"Day"&SEQUENCE(3),SUM(N(CHOOSE(XMATCH(A1,d),'Day1'!$P$6:$U$46,'Day2'!$P$6:$U$46,'Day3'!$P$6:$U$462)=$B42))/144) this creates a long formula, but avoids volatility of INDIRECT, which may benefit performance. (change sequence(3) to sequence(10) and add these ranges)

Hi P.b - Just want to thank you, the suggested formula solved not one but three of my problems :) I only understood it to 95% the third time I used for a a different task so I'm still not 100% confident with it, but at least I was able to modify and apply it to two more challenges that I had with my file :)). So, once again, a big thank you ! Not sure where I can award the winning/working solution to you on this page :(

You have sheet name in B41 cell. Then try the following formula-
=(COUNTIF(INDIRECT("'" & B41 & "'!$P$6:$U$46"),$B42)/6)/24


Thanks for the solution proposed, but it's not working in its displayed form. Should l add anything to it ?

In addition to P.b's suggestion to avoid INDIRECT,
you may want to experiment using 3-D references as well:

LET etc. will work on Excel 2021 and later
Day number in dropdown needs to match the tab order (for_day needs to be updated if this is changed)

=LET(
    rows_for_all_days, VSTACK('Day1:Day4'!$P$6:$U$46),
    num_rows, ROWS('Day1'!$P$6:$U$46),
    num_days, ROWS(rows_for_all_days) / num_rows,
    for_day, --SUBSTITUTE($B$41, "Day", ""),
    value, $B$42,
    rows_for_day, SEQUENCE(num_rows, , (for_day - 1) * num_rows + 1),
    count_if_for_day, SUM(
        N(CHOOSEROWS(rows_for_all_days, rows_for_day) = value)
    ),
    count_if_for_day / 6 / 24
)


